# Creating Strings corresponding to Location Co-ordinates

Tags: data-mining

What are some Python libraries which can convert a (X,Y) tuple to strings?

(1.23,4.56) yields strings “1_4”, “12_45”, “123_456”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with NLP or text-mining (as you claim in the attached tags), or data science in general. It's a pure programming question best suitable for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Moreover, you don't really need any libraries to do, what you want to do. A simple function will do. NOTE: I am using `map` and `reduce` functions on purpose to include at least a little bit of data science-related stuff (WINK):

```
coord = (1.23, 4.56)

def get_coord(coord):
   coord_str = map(lambda x: str(x).replace('.', ''), coord)
   for level in range(1, len(coord_str[0])+1):
      yield reduce(lambda x, y: (x[:level]+'_'+y[:level]), coord_str)

print list(get_coord(coord))
```

Running this code will result in printing:

```
['1_4', '12_45', '123_456']
```

You're not discussing any corner cases in your question, so I assume there are none.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is a part of an NLP project(text mining/analytics) to be precise. I have edited the tags to data science.